# Google Chrome extension with custom XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am developing an extension, which should do monitoring of file on the remote server, and if file changes (actually it will be appended by some text) the changed (appended) part of this file will need to be downloaded.

So, here is an example:

First, file contents was "abcd". Extension has already gotten this part. Than somebody adds on server to the file some contents and it will be "abcdefg". Here extension should get this "efg" only, not the whole contents. Is this possible to do with chrome and XMLHttpRequest?

I have made this extension for FireFox and was using XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=4-6" (for this particular situation), but doing so in Chrome results in security violation.

Also, is there a way of setting XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding", null) in Chrome? I need it for avoidance of packing response to zip format.

Comment: You could use `String.substring()`: `var res = xhr.responseText.substring(4,6);`.

Comment: Yes, but this will not save a traffic, which is a priority task.

Comment: I use `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Range", "...")` in an extension which extracts a file from a zip and it works as expected. I think your issue is elsewhere. Can you show us some code ?

Comment: Regarding the security violation, have you ensured that the URL is whitelisted at the manifest file? (at the permissions property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple working example. I hope it will help you to find your issue.

This extension downloads 4 blocks of 1024 bytes from `http://lists.w3.org/` page and displays truncated blocks in the background page console.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "background_page" : "background.html",
  "permissions": [ "http://lists.w3.org/" ]
}
```

background.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>background page</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

background.js

```
var index = 0;

function readBlock() {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", "http://lists.w3.org/");
  request.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=" + index + "-" + (index + 1023));
  request.addEventListener("load", function() {
    console.log(index, request.response.substring(0, 100) + " ...");
    index += 1024;
    if (index < 4 * 1024)
      readBlock();
  }, false);
  request.send();
}

readBlock();
```